# Diamondize a matrix

Tags: pyth

The task is to output a representation of the matrix where the top left element is on top, the anti-diagonal is the central row and the bottom right element is at the bottom.

For example, consider the following matrix:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

The diamond version of this matrix is:

```
  1
 3 2
5 4
 6
```

which would correspond to a nested array of `[[1],[3,2],[5,4],[6]]`.

**This is my program:**

```
FNUlQ=Y+Y""=QXQN+Y@QN;=Q.TQ;FNUlQ=Hx@QN""InH_1=QXQN<@QNH;FNUlQ=QXQN_@QN;=Q>Q1;pQ;
```

How it works:

(`Q` is implicitly assigned to the evaluation of input)

```
FNUlQ=Y+Y""=QXQN+Y@QN;
FNUlQ                ;         for N in range(len(Q)):
     =Y+Y""                        Y = Y+""
           =QXQN+Y@QN              Q[N] = Y+Q[N]

=Q.TQ;                         assign('Q',transpose(Q))

FNUlQ=Hx@QN""InH_1=QXQN<@QNH;
FNUlQ                          for N in range(len(Q)):
     =Hx@QN""                      H = Q[N].index_of("")
             InH_1                 if H != -1:
                  =QXQN<@QNH           Q[N] = Q[N][:H]

FNUlQ=QXQN_@QN;
FNUlQ         ;                for N in range(len(Q)):
     =QXQN_@QN                     Q[N] = reverse(Q[N])

=Q>Q1;                         Q = Q[1:]

pq;                            print(Q)
```

I am especially interested in advice on the readability of my code.

[Link to my first attempt](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=FNUlQ%3DY%2BY%22%22%3DQXQN%2BY%40QN%3B%3DQ.TQ%3BFNUlQ%3DHx%40QN%22%22InH_1%3DQXQN%3C%40QNH%3BFNUlQ%3DQXQN_%40QN%3B%3DQ%3EQ1%3BpQ%3B&input=[[1%2C2]%2C[3%2C4]%2C[5%2C6]]&debug=0).